# how to scale iphone 5 and iphone 6 screen with same storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

Please help me out,if it is related to autolayout then please instruct me,I have to build app in iphone 5 ,6, 6+ and ipads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about Apple's new Size Classes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

The idea in Xcode 6, is that you use one storyboard where the views can be dynamically resized and more importantly, get set with layout constraints for all devices.

Basically you have 3 x 3 sizes: Compact, Any, Regular (small to large). It is best to start with 'Any,Any' (which mean really it should work for all sizes). Other sizes that are not 'Any' will 'remember' specific constraints. Meaning, if you set some different constraints in 'Compact', other sizes will not be ill affected.

In my experience, it take some decant effort to get it to work right, I often miss the old way where I could really nail things, but it's a new technology and it will take its time. I'm saying there is some learning curve (depends on how complex your views are).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing it:

1. In storybard on the bottom of Xcode screen you select any width and any height (middle on blue bar on the bottom of storyboard screen).
2. You position everything with constraints (right on blue bar on the bottom of storyboard screen).
3. Thats pretty much it.